# Hibernate Envers how get entitie's revision with his associated object from the same revision

Tags: java, hibernate, associations, hibernate-envers

We are working with Hibernate Envers, with a Class A containing association with Class B. We get our object A from a certain revision number and we do it with success. But, seems like the associated object B is in his last revision and not sync with the Object A's revision historic...

We are two ideas for now, 
--> Modify the revised entity to include the revision number of his associated object
--> SQL selection with timestamp comparaison

Seems to be very loud and hardwork ...

So, before hard coding ! How could we load the good revision of an associated object ?

Comment: Please post your mappings for both entity `A` and `B` to give us an idea of how you've mapped them.  A snippet of code where you modify them and expect a correct revision would be helpful to explain why you observe what you do.

Comment: yes agree with @Naro